# URL containing "&quot;M&#xe4;&#xe4;s&quot;" ASCII, HEX what is it and how to convert it?

Tags: php, facebook, ascii

How can I convert that to a readable string with PHP or smarty?

(Must be easy, as I see this editor converts it to a readable string without doing anything)

The sample from the title is from this string:

```
 Wer ist am Wochenende alles an der &quot;M&#xe4;&#xe4;s&quot; anzutreffen?
```

Right below the string is written right:

```
Wer ist am Wochenende alles an der "Määs" anzutreffen?
```

I've got this problem with trying to include a facebook RSS feed. There are more of these strings if you want more of these here we go:

http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=113971395284126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it looks like with this, you need `htmlspecialchars_decode()` rather than `html_entity_decode()`;

With htmlspecialchars_decode() you get "Määs", with html_entity_decode() you get "MÃ¤Ã¤s".

Comment: in smarty "$arr.title|html_entity_decode:$smarty.const.ENT_QUOTES:'utf-8'|wordwrap:60" does the job. so it seems that html_entity_decode() works fine but htmlspecialchars_decode() does not

Comment: Not sure about smarty, if that works for you great. With straight PHP I got the results as listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Try `html_entity_decode()` to change it to readable string.

Comment: do you also know how "&quot;M&#xe4;&#xe4;s&quot;" is called? what kind of string is this? is just a html special char or what?

Comment: Yes, those are just special character codes (the hexh values): http://webdesign.about.com/library/bl_htmlcodes.htm